# Most efficient/elegant way to calculate Num Users for Current Month

Tags: dax

I have the following which seems to function ok but looks like I might have done my usual trick of not keeping as simple as possible - what is the elegant version of this measure?

```
Num Users for Current Month = 
VAR 
    MaxMonth = MONTH(LASTDATE(ALL('Date'[Day Marker])))
VAR
    MaxYear = YEAR(LASTDATE(ALL('Date'[Day Marker])))
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Num Users]
    ,FILTER(
        'Date',
        MONTH('Date'[Day Marker]) = MaxMonth
        &&
        YEAR('Date'[Day Marker]) = MaxYear
) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you are not selecting the current month. You are selecting the last available month in your selection of dates.

I would rather expand my date table with an extra field: IsCurrentMonth:

```
IsCurrentMonth = 
IF (
    YEAR ( Date[Date] ) = YEAR ( TODAY () )
        && MONTH ( Date[Date] ) = MONTH ( TODAY () ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

Then you measure can be rewritten towards:

```
CALCULATE([Num Users], Date[IsCurrentMonth]="yes")
```

Comment: hmmm .... you touched on a sore point Wim! the specific report I need this for is in Power BI Direct Query mode so a calculated column is not an option

Comment: If you are using a microsoft sql database, you can change your source query to have the same result.
case when eomonth(mydatefield) = eomonth(getdate()) then 'yes' else 'no'  end as iscurrentmonth

Comment: I'm connecting to a 2billion row tabular model

Comment: When using a tabular model as back-end, then I would definitely add the current month to your date table. This will have a minor impact on ram usage. 365 records by year, for 20 years, in total this gives 7300 extra field values.

Comment: Cheers Wim, although if we assume that I can’t change the model is there a more canonical version of my function?

Comment: CALCULATE(
    [Num Users]
    ,FILTER(
        'Date',
        MONTH('Date'[Day Marker]) = month(now())
        &&
        YEAR('Date'[Day Marker]) = year(now())
) )